# Knitr from linux command line

Tags: r, linux, knitr

I have a very simple knitr script. It works perfectly with rstudio on my windows laptop.

````
---
title: "Descriptives and PCA"
output:
pdf_document: default
html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```
#TEST

```{r}
print(getwd())
```
````

I run the script on a linux cluster using the following script

```
cd ./__workspace/R/pipeline
Rscript -e "library(knitr); stitch('pipelineDescriptive.Rmd')"
```

It doesn't work. It prints out a pdf which is simply a copy of the Rmd file code.

The console prints out the following two issues:

```
|................................                                 |  50%
label: auto-report
Error in parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) :
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
|.........................................                        |  62%

Warning message:
In highr::hilight(x, format, prompt = options$prompt, markup = opts$markup) :
  the syntax of the source code is invalid; the fallback mode is used
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: A few comments: 1) use `stitch_rmd` then the error at 50 % should be away. 2) Why not using `Rscript -e "library(markdown); render('pipelineDescriptive.Rmd')"` ?

Comment: It works! Maybe you could post as answer. Deserves some upvotes. Note, I think library is rmarkdown and the render is rmarkdown::render

Comment: Yes it should be `rmarkdown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `library(rmarkdown)` and then

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('pipelineDescriptive.Rmd')"
```

If you want to use `library(knitr)`:

```
Rscript -e "knitr::stitch_rmd('pipelineDescriptive.Rmd')"
```